# How to remove the divider between widgets when using `statusBar.addPermanentWidget()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qstatusbar

Is it possible to remove the divider line between two widgets that were added to the status bar using `.addPermanentWidget()`? I suspect that it is possible, but I haven't really found any literature on how to proceed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStatusBar, QLabel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(statusBar)
        statusBar.addPermanentWidget(QLabel("Label: "))
        statusBar.addPermanentWidget(QLabel("Data"))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Not all widget styles will draw separators. What platform are you on, and what is the output of `QApplication.style().objectName()`?

Comment: Output is windowsvista, I'm currently developing under Windows 10.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use the default status-bar, rather than setting a new one? It probably won't, but it would be good to rule that out.

Comment: @ekhumoro there was not change using the default status-bar.

Comment: The [stylesheet examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qstatusbar) suggest it might be possible to set the border to zero for status-bar items. But I can't test it myself, so I have no idea whether that will work. If it doesn't, it will probably be necessary to reimplement the paint-event of `QStatusBar`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Setting the `QStatusBar::Item` stylesheet removed the divider..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to remove the divider between the two elements you need to set the stylesheet for `QStatusBar::item` in either Qt Creator, or the project source.

> Qt Creator Example:

[image]

> Project Source Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStatusBar, QLabel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        statusBar = QStatusBar()

        statusBar.setStyleSheet('QStatusBar::item {border: None;}')

        self.setStatusBar(statusBar)
        statusBar.addPermanentWidget(QLabel("Label: "))
        statusBar.addPermanentWidget(QLabel("Data"))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to combine several widgets into one to group them, something like the C++ below:

```
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    QLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->setMargin(0);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setText("Recording status");
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QLabel *m_RecordingStatus = new QLabel;
    m_RecordingStatus->setFrameShape(QFrame::Shape::Box);
    m_RecordingStatus->setFixedWidth(100);

    layout->addWidget(m_RecordingStatus);
    ui.m_statusBar->addPermanentWidget(widget);
```

You can group associated widgets to be together between dividers.